# Iframe onLoad won't fire when dumping a file?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, http

I have a simple `iframe`

```
 <iframe class="ifr" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Which has `onload` handler attached to it.

```
$(".ifr").on('load',function (){
 alert("iframe loaded")
});
```

There is also 2 buttons :

[image]

When I press the first button ( which sets to a site ( nevermind which)  - it **does** alert :

[image]

However when I set it to [**mypage**](http://selfservice.davidshield.com/exampales/eeeee.aspx) (which dumps a picture) - the picture **is** downloaded **but** it doe not fire the `onload`.

When I press on the *second* buttons it redirects to a page which its code is:

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=/images/about_us_bkg.jpg");
 Response.AddHeader("content-length", File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/images/about_us_bkg.jpg")).Length.ToString());
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/images/about_us_bkg.jpg"));
 Response.End();
```

I believe it is related to `Response.End();`.

Question :

- Why (if ever) it is affected by `Response.End` ? I mean the browser **did send a response** ( as a picture)  ....so?
- How can I solve this  so that when the picture loads( or iframe completes) , it will fire the onload event ?

**p.s.** why do I need it ?

When a user press "download file" , in client side -I show loading animation and the `onload` suppose to remove the "loading" animation.

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/osipak/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Why (if ever) it is affected by Response.End ? I mean the browser 
> did send a response ( as a picture) , so the request is completed ....no?
> ```

I don't think it is related to Response.End (unless it works when you remove the Response.End)
You may use `Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead of `Response.End` ( see [Correct usage of Asp.Net Response.TransmitFile and Response.End()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14566781/1236044) )

> How can I solve this so that when the picture loads( or iframe completes) , 
>      it will fire the onload event ?

I think the problem comes from the fact that your iframe content is not an html document or an img element. So it does not trigger any load event.

You may have your aspx page have two different behaviours varying on a query string parameter (or just have two pages) :

- one that serves the image (say *img.aspx*, the one you already have)
- one, say *document.aspx*, which url will be used as `src` attribute of your `iframe`. *document.aspx* builds a whole html document containing an img element which `src` will be *img.aspx*

Hope this will help